# How to insert nothing or a blankinto the list if it is not alternately in python?

Tags: python, list

For example, here is a list:

```
['1','a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c', '4', 'd', 'e', '6', '7']
```

How to insert ' ' into the list where '5' and 'f' are missing and separate them into two lists?

I would like to have the following ouput.

Expected output:

```
list 1 : ['1','2','3','4',' ','6','7']
list 2 : ['a','b','c','d','e',' ',' ']
```

Comment: Please (re-)read [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). “Show/tell me how to solve this coding problem” [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). We expect you to [make an honest attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 0):

This code does the thing :

```
l = ['1','a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c', '4', 'd', 'e', '6', '7','g','h']
l1 = []
l2 = []

# Create an int2character list
letters = [chr(c+97) for c in range(26)]

# Finding maximum character in the list
maximum = 0
for character in l:
    try:
        maximum = max(maximum, int(character))
    except:
        maximum = max(maximum, ord(character)-96)
        
# Adding sequentially the characters into l1 or l2
for i in range(1,maximum+1):
    if str(i) in l: # This can be optimized
        l1.append(str(i))
    else:
        l1.append('')
    if chr(i+96) in l:
        l2.append(chr(i+96))
    else:
        l2.append('')
print(l1)
print(l2)
```

Note that this can be optimized in O(n) if the input list is ordered, here it is in O(n^2).